# Destructor not being called upon program exit

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, destructor

I'm writing a very simple debugger and I defined a `class` called `BREAKPOINT_INFO` that contains information about breakpoints set.

```
class BREAKPOINT_INFO
{
public:

    HANDLE hProcess;

    PCHAR  lpBreakPoint;

    CHAR   instr;

    BOOL   justCalled;

    //Set default values
    BREAKPOINT_INFO()
    {
        hProcess     = NULL;

        lpBreakPoint = NULL;

        instr        = 0x00;

        justCalled   = FALSE;
    }

    //Destructor
    ~BREAKPOINT_INFO()
    {
        //Let me know the destructor is being called
        MessageBox(NULL, "Destructor called", NULL, MB_OK);

        DWORD dwError        = 0;
        LPCSTR szErrorRest   = (LPCSTR)"Error restoring original instruction: ";
        LPCSTR szErrorHanlde = (LPCSTR)"Error closing process handle: ";
        std::ostringstream oss;

        if(hProcess != NULL && lpBreakPoint != NULL)
        {
            //write back the original instruction stored in instr
            if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBreakPoint, &instr, sizeof(CHAR), NULL))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();

                oss << szErrorRest << dwError;

                MessageBox(NULL, oss.str().c_str(), "ERROR", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I need the destructor to clean up any breakpoints set however the deconstructor is never called and I'm not quite sure why that is in my particular case.

Here's main.cpp:

```
BREAKPOINT_INFO instrMov;

//GetProcModuleHandle is a function I made to get the handle of a 
//of a module in a remote process
LPVOID      lpServerDll = (LPVOID)GetProcModuleHandle(dwPid, szServerDll);

//the instructions address is relative to the starting address of the server dll. Hence the offset.
PCHAR       lpInstr     = (PCHAR)((DWORD)lpServerDll+instr_offset);

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, dwPid);

//sets the breakpoint 
instrMov.InitializeBreakPoint(hProcess, lpInstr);

while(1)
    {
        if(!instrMov.justCalled)
        {
            instrMov.SetBreakPoint();
        }

        if(instrMov.justCalled)
        {
            instrMov.justCalled = FALSE;
        }

        if(WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, 0))
        {
            ProcessDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, lpBreakPoints, 3);

            ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
        }
    }

return 0; //<---never reaches return
```

It's a never ending loop so the program, at the moment, never actually reaches the return. It has to be terminated with either `Ctrl+C` or by closing the terminal. Not sure if this could be causing the destructor to not be called or not.

Any information, solutions, etc would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: BTW, it's called a "destructor", not a "deconstructor".

Comment: your problem in your program logic.

Comment: Programs are not usually designed to be ended abruptly by things like `Ctrl-C`. That signal can be intercepted but it may just be simpler to end your program normally.

Comment: Can't we see a [mcve]? The code in the question is neither complete nor minimal, nor verifiable.

Comment: Minimal code would be: `struct X { ~X() { cout << "dtor"; } }; int main() { X x; while ( true ) {} return 0; }`.

Comment: @IInspectable I added more code.

Comment: We don't want more code. We want **less**. I gave you the [mcve] in my previous comment. And that's really all you need in terms of code. Also, all the prose about your debugger is meaningless to the problem at hand and can be scrapped.

Comment: @IInspectable The guidelines it gives are that it's verifiable. If I don't include what I included it won't compile and reproduce the problem. However I have stripped a lot of code and left what I believe is what you mean.

Comment: The guidelines also state, that it needs to be minimal. The code I posted is both minimal and complete and exhibits the issue you are trying to solve. If you believe that this is not the case, explain why.

Comment: Solved. Whenever it goes through the main debug loop I use `GetAsyncKeyState` to check whether or not the escape key(`VK_ESCAPE`) is pressed. If so `return 0;`.

Comment: That neither explains, what the root cause is, nor is it a general solution. The root cause is, that destructors don't run when a process is forcefully terminated, as is the case, when the console receives a [Ctrl]+C signal. One solution is to set up a console event handler by calling [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016.aspx), and respond to [Ctrl]+C from your code.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried setting up a handler routine to for `CTRL_C_EVENT`, however I was unable to find a way to make the process terminate from main(as in `return`). I tried doing a `throw` `catch` that would `throw` when the `CTRL_C_EVENT`  happened. The `catch` was in the main debug loop. When it caught it, it was supposed to `return 0`. Instead it would say the process tried to terminate in an unusual way. Then I tried using the `exit` function however this doesn't call the `dtor`. So I am stumped as to another solution.

Comment: None of that explains, why you **still** haven't offered a [mcve] in this question (although I provided one that you literally only needed to copy-paste). If you cannot set up a control handler, that's a different question, and you should ask one for that problem. If you do, please do make sure to provide a [mcve], that's **really** minimal.

Answer (score -3):

you have to handle SIGINT signal, otherwise program is terminated abnormally and dtors are not called.

Comment: [`SIGINT` is not supported for any Win32 application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx).